# Use of a comma after a "that"-qualified subject

Tags: commas

> Some things[,] that have a value[,] derive their value from other things.

The first comma seems like it would only be valid if "that" were switched for "which", but obviously "which" feels wrong in this context. The second comma seems to be too strong of a pause in the sentence flow when read aloud but, without it, the subject of the trailing clause "feels" ambiguous. I say "feels", because obviously there is no ambiguity to speak of; rather, without the second comma, the flow of the sentence feels like it places emphasis on the middle part of the sentence rather than the subject.

How should the sentence be punctuated, or alternatively, how should the sentence be rearranged to flow more correctly than it currently does?

Comment: Why do you want to insert commas? "That have a value" is an integrated relative clause, thus commas would be quite wrong here.

Comment: @BillJ I explained my thought process in the question. Not sure what was unclear...? Why the downvote?

Comment: Sorry, Nathan, I gave you another downvote because I think Bill's wholly correct.

How can you say *obviously there is no ambiguity to speak of* then ask a question which is only about ambiguity then not accept a clear and simple answer.

Do you think this might be better in *English Language Learners*?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin I thought it was obvious, but maybe I was wrong - I'm ok with that. Shame that meant I got a downvote rather than just discussing it with me though :-(

Comment: Mainly I was just given pause because it seemed like there should be a comma there, but I couldn't put my finger on what was actually correct, hence my posing the original question. I'd hoped for some assistance clarifying this. Downvoted instead though. My apologies if I violated any guidelines I was unaware of. If I may make a suggestion- newer users will be less inclined to opt out of participation if they are engaged with before being penalised for any unwitting lack of clarity in their questions.